# Drupal services forbbiden error on put but not on post

Tags: services

I'm using [Drupal Services Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) to upload data to my site. It works good on local host, and I can do PUT and POST without problems. But after upload my site to a shared hosting, I can do POST, but PUT always get "Forbidden" errors. For exmple, when I try to update a taxonomy term, it returns "Forbbiden. You don't have permission to access taxonomy_term/2601", where 2601 is a taxonomy term previously created with POST and the same web service's user. And this user has permission to edit this term.
Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: are you sending the sessionid, cookies and token in the header for your PUT request?

Comment: Yes. As I said, It works good on my local server (xampp). The problem has appeared after upload the site to a shared hosting. POST works but PUT not.

Comment: What kind of web server is your shared hosting running? e.g. apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is an apache web server you could try this in your .htaccess file.

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
  Allow from all
</Limit>
```

Otherwise you may need to contact the hosting support to see if they have restricted PUT requests

Comment: That is the problem. The hosting have a mod_security restriction not allowing PUT nor DELETE. I have requested to change this restriction. Thanks for your answer.